# How to find this error in Hibernate 5.6.4 with MySQL 8.0.29

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

***Error***

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1406)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3285)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2420)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
        at com.tapacad.application.Program2.main(Program2.java:34)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1402)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernatedb.student' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
        ... 21 more
```

***Student.java***

```
package com.tapacad.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    
    // Attributes
    @Id
    @Column(name = "roll")
    private int roll;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "marks")
    private int marks;
    
    // Constructor
    public Student() {
        
    }

    public Student(int roll, String name, String email, int marks) {
        super();
        this.roll = roll;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    // Setters and Getters
    
    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    
}
```

***Program2.java***

```
package com.tapacad.application;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.tapacad.model.Student;

public class Program2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Session session = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        
        try {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.configure();
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
            
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            
            // Create Transaction
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            
            // CRUD Operation
            Student s = new Student(1,"Alex","alex@gmail.com",97);
            session.save(s);
            
            transaction.commit();
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
        
    }

}
```

***hibernate.cfg.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    
    
    
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver.class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
            <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">mysql@123</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
            <property name = "hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">update</property>
            <property name = "show_sql">update</property>
        
        </session-factory>
        
        
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typos alert!

Below are the correct ones. Please fix them.

`hbm2ddl`

`driver_class`

`hibernate.dialect`

`hibernate.show_sql`

Comment: Sir, it's not working

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: When I Deleted my project and created the project again, It running properly.

Comment: Even without the above changes its working?

Comment: No I just Change hibernate.hbm2dll.auto To hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto